# What's required for Skinlink to work?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4

I'm a bit confused on how to set up skinlink on electronics. Would a player need a built-in commlink or a commlink connected to a trode net in order for the skinlink to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skinlink allows you to interact with a device by contact instead of wifi and wires. Your body basically becomes the wire. So you need something on both end of that wire right?

Do you need a commlink? Yes, physical commlink or implant. Skinlink is just how you connect to the devices.

You also need the accessory on **both** ends. Whatever device you want and your commlink should have the accessory.

Answer (score 3):

> With skinlink, a device is adapted to send and receive  data transmitted through the electrical field on the surface of metahuman
>   skin. Though limited to touch, skinlink communication has the 
>   advantage of being protected from signal interception or jamming.

It depends on what type of electronics you're looking to connect. As I understand the above passage, Skinlink uses a body's natural electrical field to connect to any other external device that has Skinlink or any internal device within a Metahuman's body.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood skinlink. Basically it's a way to connect two devices through a player's body rather than using wires or wi-fi?

Comment: Yes exactly, as it describes its just more secure/convenient than wires or WiFi.